# Can't get jQuery file upload to work in oneupUploader bundle

Tags: symfony, jquery-file-upload, oneupuploaderbundle

Seems like I followed the [docs](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/frontend_blueimp.md) to the letter,  but I can't get jQuery file upload to work using the oneupUploader bundle in symfony2. No error is displayed, nothing in the browser console, nothing happens.

I've tried this:

```
{% block javascripts %}

{% javascripts '@OOTNBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js'
               '@OOTNBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js'
               '@OOTNBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js' %}

<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({});
});

</script>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" multiple />

// ..
```

(jQuery's included in the parent template). After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831257/cant-get-jquery-file-uploader-to-appear-on-page), I've tried replacing `$('#fileupload').fileupload({});` with

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
```

to no avail. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to load jQuery at the end of body tag and also after jQuery load OOTNBlogBundle js assets.

Comment: Just tried but it didn't change anything

Comment: Any console logs from jQuery or bundle?

Comment: Just the assets being fetched, I think:

`GET 
http://localhost/projects/ootn_symf/web/includes/js/jquery-1.11.2.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 22ms]
GET 
http://localhost/projects/ootn_symf/web/app_dev.php/js/55ac7f5_jquery.ui.widget_1.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 3231ms]
GET 
http://localhost/projects/ootn_symf/web/app_dev.php/js/55ac7f5_jquery.iframe-transport_2.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2939ms]
GET 
http://localhost/projects/ootn_symf/web/app_dev.php/js/55ac7f5_jquery.fileupload_3.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2940ms]`

Comment: Check networking logs, ajax posts etc.

Comment: I get a `304 not modified` error for all the js assets. Is this where the problems comes from? I get the same for some css and img assets and they're displayed fine

Comment: Install assets, check web/bundles and add assets like this in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% javascripts
    'bundles/path/to/the/js/assets/*.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I switched to dropzone.js and it seems to be a bit more gentle. Thank you for trying to help though